# Maven Compiler Plugin Error (maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile)

Tags: java, maven

This is the error i get as a popup in my *pom.xml* file and i seriously dont know why this is happening at all

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile
>   (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

**POM**

```
    ....
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>    **<--HERE!!**
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

**ALSO** i may add that i have 3 projects in the workspace and every single one displays the same error in the pom.xml file

**SOLUTION**

This is what worked for me. Its not very clear why..

```
   ...
       <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no 
                    influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[3.2,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>  
     ...
```

Comment: Have a look here in the [maven to eclipse plugin help](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your POM if you are using m2Eclipse which seem like it.

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse 
            m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

On the official [site](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) you can find more answers.

EDIT:
 Did you change the pluginExecutionFilter? 
It should contain your plugin info.

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.1</version>
```

And then change the goals to fit you need too

Comment: i still get the same error , but in ta different line

Comment: Check the EDIT. I am sorry for missleading you the first time

Comment: i awarded you , because you were closer to the solution :)

Comment: And may I inquire what the solution was? (Anyway thank you)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse you should be able to hover over the red error and it will give you a couple of quick fix options. One of them adds some xml to the pom to suppress that message. That's how I always fix this.

Comment: the solution for Eclipse is to Ignore the actual problem

Comment: It won't affect your build. Just tells eclipse to ignore it. Maven will still build it like you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think your probleme is exec-maven-plugin , why you do:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Move it with profil for example.